# Cannot find the EntityType - SessionEntityType name is composed of Session name and EntityType.display_name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, dialogflow-es, google-api-python-client

Even though I have provided the correct information in the `SessionEntityTypes`, the I am getting the following errors. Tried from both REST & Python options, please let me know if there is anything which I am missing in the integrations.

**Request**
HTTP Method: POST

```
{
  "name": "projects/{projectId}/locations/asia-northeast1/agent/environments/draft/users/-/sessions/c973fe-e44-9b5-34e-b404439b7/entityTypes/speciality_types",
  "entities": [
    {
      "value": "APPLE_KEY",
      "synonyms": [
        "apple",
        "green apple",
        "crabapple"
      ]
    },
    {
      "value": "ORANGE_KEY",
      "synonyms": [
        "orange"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "entityOverrideMode": "ENTITY_OVERRIDE_MODE_SUPPLEMENT"
}
```

**Response**

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "com.google.apps.framework.request.BadRequestException: Cannot find the EntityType of SessionEntityType 'projects/{projectId}/locations/asia-northeast1/agent/environments/draft/users/-/sessions/c973fe-e44-9b5-34e-b404439b7/entityTypes/speciality_types'. Please note that the SessionEntityType name is composed of Session name and EntityType.display_name.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

**Google Try this API**

[image]

Comment: In order to better understand, please address the following: 1. Can you confirm [the entity](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/entities-session) “speciality_types” has already been created for this agent? Have you tried [listing](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.environments.users.sessions.entityTypes/list) the entities using the API to confirm successful creation? (continues below)

Comment: 2. What [SessionEntityType method](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.environments.users.sessions.entityTypes#methods) are you using? (e.g. create, patch, etc) 3. What [API version](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest) are you using? 4. Are you able to provide the complete error trace?

Comment: 1. Yes, "speciality_types" already exists in the agent and the listing entities shows empty result because the creation api is failing.
2. HTTP Method: POST (updated above)
3. API Version: V3
4. API Trace Response already provided above.

Let me know if you would require any other details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to paraphrase the issue here in order to ensure I’m not missing any details: you are attempting to create a sessionEntity using the [“Try this API” tool](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.environments.users.sessions.entityTypes/create), which is the Create (POST) version 2.

The issue is that the “name” you are passing in the request body does not have a valid format [for API v2](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.environments.users.sessions.entityTypes).

The format you are using for the name is:
`projects/<ProjectID>/locations/<LocationID>/agent/environments/<EnvironmentID>/users/<UserID>/sessions/<SessionID>/entityTypes/<EntityTypeDisplayName>`
Below I’ve listed the two valid name formats for v2 and as you can see the *locations/<Location ID>* is not needed:

```
projects/<Project ID>/agent/sessions/<Session ID>/entityTypes/<Entity Type Display Name>
```

and

```
projects/<Project ID>/agent/environments/<Environment ID>/users/<User ID>/sessions/<Session ID>/entityTypes/<Entity Type Display Name>
```

The below request body works as intended, I tested it in the same [“Try this API” tool](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.environments.users.sessions.entityTypes/create):

```
{
"name":"projects/{projectId}/agent/environments/draft/users/-/sessions/c973fe-e44-9b5-34e-b404439b7/entityTypes/speciality_types",
  "entities":[
     {
        "value":"APPLE_KEY",
        "synonyms":[
           "apple",
           "green apple",
           "crabapple"
        ]
     },
     {
        "value":"ORANGE_KEY",
        "synonyms":[
           "orange"
        ]
     }
  ],
  "entityOverrideMode":"ENTITY_OVERRIDE_MODE_SUPPLEMENT"
}
```

Comment: Thank you @roberto. The issue was dialogflow CX vs dialogflow ES :faceplam: